# Does DB normalization compromise query speed?

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database

Imagine following database model:

```
Volunteer:
-id(PK)
-person_id
-organization
-hours_a_week
```

person_id is a foreign key. Now, Person has 2 foreign keys itself pointing to `Address` & `Workplace`. I would of course like to display the contact information of a Volunteer in my application, and I will fetch that from the Person model. But I would also like to display the address of a volunteer.

**So my question is this:** Will upgrading `Volunteer` to look like below 
violate any rules of normalization? The concern arises because in some parts of the application, I only care about the address of a volunteer - by changing Volunteer table to look like this I will only need to query the Address table in these situations, which should significantly increase the query speed?

```
Volunteer:
-id(PK)
-person_id
-address_id
-organization
-hours_a_week
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the query to get the volunteer's address would be faster if you put the address_id in the volunteer table.

No, you shouldn't do it.

Why?

Speed of a single query is not the only consideration, and the performance impact of not denormalising is likely to be undetectable in terms of overall system performance -- data integrity and balanced performance should both be goals of the design.

Comment: If I'm assuming that querying address will take twice as long without the address_id in volunteer, and that query speeds are something to worry about in general, then this answer leaves me wanting more - why shouldnt i do it?

Comment: "why shouldnt i do it?" Because every time a user updates the PERSON.ADDRESS_ID your application needs to update the VOLUNTEER.ADDRESS_ID . "If I'm assuming" Don't assume. Our industry is littered with shonky code and shonky data models because developers assumed instead of running benchmarks. There's way too much voodoo and guesswork for a sector which pretends to be a scientific or engineering discipline. Besides, even if it does take twice as long, what is the impact of 0.002ms versus 0.001ms? Compared to the impact of maintaining a sub-optimal data model?

Answer (score 2):

"Will upgrading Volunteer to look like below violate any rules of normalization?"

Assuming that "multiple volunteering" (same person volunteering X hrs for organization Y and P hrs for organization Q) is allowed and supported, and assuming the address_id value for each person would have to be identical to the one stated in Person, yes it does.

You'll have Person_id ===> Address_Id and in the volunteering table that's an FD out of a non-key.